# Multiple Time Frames having 2 indicators outside of parameters at same time

Tags: new-operator, indicator

What do I want to create – 
I want to be alerted when all three of the following time frames have both indicators outside of certain parameters at the same time. (all above or all below)
4 HR 
1HR 
15MIN
RSI (13,close) High value 70.00 Low Value 30.00
Full Stoch (33,22,11)  High Value 80.00 and Low Value 20.00
Alert when 
4HR FS and RSI outside of channels -(all above or all below)
1HR FS and RSI outside of channels -(all above or all below)
15min FS and RSI outside of channels -(all above or all below)

Comment: @matthiasbe - I am sorry however I am brand new to this forum - I see you have edited the Question however does this mean you will be creating the code? I look forward to your reply.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I have no knowledge of any solution to your problem. I edited your question so that it is more easy to read by other people, using StackOverflow formatting usage. Unfortunately you apparently reverted my changes

Comment: As is, your question has strong formatting issues. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some insights about good formatting. Sometimes your question can be interesting but a lack of good formatting will decrease the chance to get an answer